# Code igniter return index keys vs. associative on unbuffered_row

Tags: sql, codeigniter

i have the following line of code in a project:

```
        while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array')) { .. etc ..
```

logging the values of `$row` it is associative - and the DB column names are *quite long*.

How do I return `$row` as indexed from 0 to n, vs. associatively?  i already know the column names.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter has no query related method that returns numeric indexed results. You could easily make a method in MY_model and convert your results, or just simply do like this:

```
// For results (more than one row)
foreach( $query->result_array() as $row )
    $results[] = array_values( $row );

// For a single row
$row = array_values( $query->row_array() );

// For the unbuffered_row
while ($row = array_values($query->unbuffered_row('array'))) { .. etc ..
```

I tried the following test, and believe it may be your answer, but it would only work if you're using MySQLi:

```
$this->load->database();

$query = $this->db->get('users');

if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    while( $row = $query->result_id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM) )
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $row );
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Comment: That would only _add_ time to the process.  Since some returns have millions of rows, I'm trying to _natively_ use integers vs. field names.

Comment: CodeIgniter has no native solution. Been using it since 2009. It's not there.

Comment: I updated my answer with what might work for you, but only if you're using the mysqli driver.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because it's informative and does answer the question (even if only for MYSQLI).

Comment: I believe the CodeIgniter development team would have made such a feature available if all drivers had the ability to return such an array. I don't have experience with all of the drivers, but I'd quess that at least one or more of them simply can't do what you want, and that's why it's not a CodeIgniter database library feature.